# Send mail using rnote domino in Java

Tags: java, email, sendmail, lotus

I'm working on some application which should send mail sometimes. Unfortunately administrator said that I can't send mail over traditional smtp protocol because he blocks it.

He told me that there is 2 ways to do it:
1) "set relay server to application in this case somestringrnotesmtp.domain.com"

In this case it looks like some smtp server provided by Lotus rnotes. But when I try to send mail using org.apache.commons.mail I'm getting exception

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: somestringrnotesmtp.domain.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1388)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:317)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:207)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 47 more
```

1. "use unix sendmail for this purpose"
   I have no idea how to do it this way. Is there any java library which does that?

Comment: See this question for answers on using SMTP with Domino: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038819/sending-email-with-java-apache-commons-mail-through-lotus-notes

Comment: Admin was clear about that SMTP on Domino is not allowed. He said that smtp is disabled for security purpose and this server can be used only for "relay".

Comment: The error indicates you are trying to use SMTP.

Comment: That's why I'm asking what should I use in this case.